# Unity OnParticleTrigger() get Collider it collides with

Tags: unity-game-engine, system, 2d-games, particles

I wanted to make a shot with a particle system and if one of the particles collides with something, then the opponent should get damage. I use the trigger function because I want the particles to continue flying after colliding. And in case you are wondering why I don't use a raycast: if I work with a raycast, the opponent gets harm without the particles arriving.

My Code:

```
private void OnParticleTrigger()
    {
        if (!hitObjects.Contains(other.gameObject))
        {
            other.GetComponent<IDamageable>().GetDamage(PlayerScript.instance.damage);
            hitObjects.Add(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

where I would like to have the opponent's collider later, I have already inserted "other"

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! What exactly is the question?

Comment: The question is: How can I access the collider the particle collides with?

Comment: Can you use OnParticleCollision? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnParticleCollision.html

Comment: No, it isn't possible for me because I don't want to collide with the object, but go through the object.

Comment: I understand... Well back in 2018 it wasn't possible: http://answers.unity.com/answers/1497598/view.html. I think particles are mostly used for visual effects but I may be wrong so I'll follow this question

Comment: So my problem is: I want to shoot but if I shoot with the raycast, the gameobject gets hit before the effect is at the gameobjects place... Do you understand?
Do you have another possible solution for this problem?

Comment: Is your problem that the projectile of the weapon is slow and the raycast is fast? You can make the weapon projectile a gameobject with a collider instead of using ray-casting.

Comment: Yea this is my problem, but If I do this with a projectile the projectile has to be exactly at the top/front of the particle system effect. How do I do that?

Comment: Why? The moment the projectile hits the target hitbox it should disappear and start a particle system effect (like blood splattering for example)

Comment: No, The shoot trails are the particles I don't have particles at the hit, but on flight time

Comment: OK but if the particle system GameObject is the child of the projectile, shouldn't the particles match the position of the projectile?

Comment: Oh man, that's such an easy and good idea why I didn't get this? Thank you

Comment: No problem. I submitted this solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the projectile a game object with a child particle system that gets triggered once the projectile hits a target